# My email acknowledgement button is not working

Tags: email

I am trying to send an email acknowledgement to my donors but every time I press the button I get the following message:

NPSP did not send acknowledgements for the following records. Acknowledgements can fail if there is no workflow rule (Acknowledgement Status EQUALS 'Send Acknowledgement') activated to send the acknowledgement, or if the records did not meet additional criteria to trigger the workflow rule. For example, if Primary Contact is not set, or if the Primary Contact's email field is empty or invalid.

How can I ensure that I have a workflow rule that says "Acknowledgement Status Equals 'Send Acknowledgement'?  Thank you!

Gabe

Comment: The best resource for  Nonprofit Success Pack support is the Salesforce Foundation's [Power of Us Hub](https://powerofus.force.com/publogin).  You'll find many different discussion groups with lots of participation from nonprofit users, consultants, and Foundation support staff.

Comment: Also check this [NPSP documentation](https://powerofus.force.com/articles/Resource/NPSP-Send-Email-Acknowledgments#!#ariaid-title2).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this on our fresh instance of the NPSP. I got the same useless error message when I followed documentation to send the acknowledgment email.

I figured out that the "Opportunity Email Acknowledgment" Workflow Rule was Disabled by default.

Steps:

• Go to Classic Setup and do a search for "Opportunity Email Acknowledgment".

• Select the Workflow rule of that name

• Click "Activate".

There was no useful online help that indicates that it needed to be activated first, at least as far as I could tell! Hopefully, this works for you!